# What size is the Canon 550D sensor?

Tags: canon

I have these options:

- 35 mm film
- Medium Format
- Canon 10D
- Canon 30D
- Canon 300D
- Canon 5D, 5D
- MKII
- Canon 450D, 1000D
- Canon 50D

Which is the closest to 550D?

Comment: As written, this is a pretty simple question to answer, but can we have some more details as to _why_ you're asking? You've presented a list of many generations of Canon digital cameras and generic film formats with no other context. What existing gear do you have? What are you trying to take pictures of? Why are these differences important to you? It'll help us give you a better answer.

Comment: Sensor sizes are useful for ordering sensor-cleaning kits, but the film options don't really make sense in that context...

Comment: Perhaps it's input for DOF calculation - although "medium format" is puzzling as it covers many sizes from 6x4½ cm to 6x17 cm.

Answer (score 10):

- Canon 450D: 22.2 x 14.8mm
- Canon 50D: 22.3 x 14.9mm
- Canon 1000D: 22.2 x 14.8mm
- Canon 30D: 22.5 x 15.0mm
- Canon 300D: 22.7 x 15.1mm
- Canon 10D: 22.7 x 15.1mm

Canon 550D is 22.3 x 14.9mm, so its same as 50D.

Answer (score 5):

10D, 30D, 300D, 450D, 1000D, 50D are all about the same size - **APS-C**.

Comment: +1 but note that it's a different (slightly smaller) "APS-C" than used by Nikon, Sony, and Pentax.

Comment: That's a good note! Had forgotten that.