# How can I know the focal length and sensor size of my webcam?

Tags: focal-length, sensor-size, webcam

I have this webcam: QHM495LM WEB CAMERA and I need to know its focal length and its sensor size, but in the specs of the webcam, it only gives me this information:

• Inbuilt sensitive microphone and Image Sensor High Quality CMOS Sensor

• Image Resolution 16 Mega Pixels (Interpolated); Light sensor to switch on 8 lights automatically when in dark

• Image Control Color saturation, brightness, sharpness and brightness is adjustable; Snap shot switch for taking still pictures

• Anti-flicker 50Hz, 60Hz or outdoor; Resolution Hardware: 500K pixels; Image Quality: RGB24 or I420

• Exposure: Auto or manual and Angle of view: 58 Degree; Interface: USB2.0; Frame Rate: 30 fps (MAX)

• Lens: f=6.0 F=2.0

• Focus Range 4cm to infinity

For the focal length, the webcam has printed in it: "f=3.85mm", but I know it changes depending on the zoom and I was wondering if the point that says "Lens: f=6.0 F=2.0" refers to range of focal length the webcam has.

And for the sensor size I don't know if I can find it in this information.

I would really appreciate your help in this, I cannot go any further in my project without this information.

Thank you for the answers in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your question has been asked earlier but seperately..

Here, [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/20376/38479)
will tell you how to find the focal length.

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26947563/3996325)
might help in finding sensor size.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works with a webcam too?

Answer (score 1):

Calculation goes as following. Angle of view will define effective (in 35mm sense) focal length of the lens. 58 degrees of angle of view will give you [roughly 39mm focal length](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/professional/standard_display/bctv_tools/bctv_range_calculator/bctv_range_angleview) (if angle is measured diagonally).

Your lens is (let's say) 6 mm by spec, that is 39/6=6.5 times smaller. Which means that sensor has crop factor of 6.5 (consider 1.5 for Nikon's DX). That means that sensor size (if it is 3:2 ratio) is 36x24mm / 6.5 = 5.5x3.7mm rectangle.

Final thought. I believe your camera [has about 500K real pixels](http://www.pnpbazaar.com/quantum-qhm495lm-25-mp-usb-pc-camera), which means that single pixel area [is about (6.4um)^2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%285.5mm*3.7mm%20%2F%20500000%29), which seems reasonable for CMOS sensors.